# Pytest assert django context_data

Tags: django, pytest

I'm trying to create pytest for a view, where I added form in get_context_data function

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["form"] = CommentForm
        return context
```

I made something like this

```
    def test_post_detail_view_queryset(self, client, supply_post):
        response = client.get(reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'slug': supply_post.slug}))
        assert response.context['form'] == True
```

But i receive error `TestPostDetailView::test_post_detail_view_queryset - AssertionError: assert <class 'comments.forms.CommentForm'> == True`.
Anyone knows how to resolve it?

Comment: First, you are assigning a class (not an instance) to `context["form"]` - I'm not sure this is what you want. Then you compare this class against `True` - why would you expect it to equal `True`?

Comment: I want to be sure that this form exists in the context.

Comment: First, it is not a form, but a class - I still doubt that is what you want. Second, do you want to know if the key is existing (e.g. `assert "form" in response.context`) or that is not `None` (`assert response.context["form"] is not None`), or something else?